# Is it a subspace or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $$\mathscr{S_1}=\lbrace(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3:a^3=b^3\rbrace$$ subspace of **R**^3?

my try:: $a^3=b^3\iff a=b$ in $\mathbb{R}$. So $\mathscr{S_1}=\lbrace(a,a,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3\rbrace$ this is a plane going through the origin so it is a subspace

Is $$\mathscr{S_2}=\lbrace(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{C}^3:a^3=b^3\rbrace$$ subspace of **C**^3?

my try:: $a^3=b^3\iff a=b$ or $a=(-b+\sqrt{-3b^2})/2=b*\rho_1$ or $a=(-b-\sqrt{-3b^2})/2=b*\rho_2$ where $\rho_1=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}2$ and $\rho_2=\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}2$ .... at the end i get it is a subspace, is my try right? if not why not?

Comment: The second will not be a subspace; that "or" changes things significantly.

Comment: For the complex, no. You should find not closed under addition. The first is a subspace. A proof using algebra language is probably  required, though I like your geometric viewpoint.

Comment: The reason that the first one works is that $x \mapsto x^3$ is injective on the reals, so $a^3 = b^3$ **iff** $a=b$. This suggests a possible way to obtain a counterexample.

Comment: @Timbuc both are closed under scalar multiplication, your example is false

Comment: @copper.hat What i don't understand is the or. So can i choose for example $a=b$ in $\mathscr{S_2}$ and $a=b*\rho_1$ in $\mathscr{S_2}$ and add them? (then it is obvious)

Comment: Well, I think it is easier to guess & verify here. Choose $a=1$ and find all complex $b$s such that $b^3=1$. This will give, say, $(1,b,0)$ and $(1,\bar{b},0)$. Then see if $(2, b+\bar{b},0)$ lies in the set.

Comment: @copper.hat okay, i was more thinking of $(-b*\rho_1,-b,-c)$ , $(b*\rho_2,b,c)$ then their sum $(b(\rho_2-\rho_1),0,0)$ which isn't there

Comment: Whatever works. A better take on my example would be the difference $(0,b-\bar{b},0)$, but I always figure out the best solution afterwards :-).

Comment: right, thanks to you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
Look at the axioms. Obviously $0\in\mathcal S_2$ and $\lambda x\in\mathcal S_2$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ and $x\in \mathcal S_2$. What will blow up is that
$$x,y\in\mathcal S_2 \not\Rightarrow x+y\in\mathcal S_2$$
Try to find a counter-example for that, it's not hard ;)

Comment: What i don't understand is the or. So can i choose for example $a=b$ in $\mathscr{S_2}$ and $a=b*\rho_1$ in $\mathscr{S_2}$ and add them? (then it is obvious)

Comment: @user211273 Yes, you can even take concrete values such as $(1,1,0) + (\omega_3,1,0) \notin \mathcal S_2$.